# How can I validate a TypeScript Definition file?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a [`.d.ts` file for Electron](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt/pull/209). Is there a command-line tool that can be used validate that the syntax of my file is correct?

Comment: The compiler will tell you if it isn't correct.

Comment: Found this on GitHub https://github.com/martinmcwhorter/grunt-ngts-templates